# How to monitor only the last n lines of a log file?

Tags: logs, monitoring, tail

I have a growing log file for which I want to display **only** the last 15 lines. Here is what I know I can do:

```
tail -n 15 -F mylogfile.txt
```

As the log file is filled, `tail` appends the last lines to the display.

I am looking for a solution that only displays the last 15 lines and get rid of the lines before the last 15 after it has been updated. Would you have an idea?

Comment: Resize your terminal window to 15 lines.

Comment: That's a good one too.

Comment: @Jonathan genius!

Comment: Couldn't upvote jonathan's comment or it loses the flavor of having 15 upvotes

Comment: That's a good question. By today's terminology one would say you want a widget for you shell script to do something like that if you want to have it all in one script in one shell (tmux would be an option otherwise). https://github.com/charmbracelet/gum is building something like that, but their features are not on this level yet.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

It might suffice to use watch:

```
$ watch tail -n 15 mylogfile.txt
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. I also learn the 'watch' command in the process.

Comment: Be aware that this solution doesn’t work if the file grows more than 15 lines between two `watch` updates. You can use `-n` to change this interval.

Comment: This is perfect! And solution works perfectly well with files longer than 15 lines...

Answer (score 34):

If you use watch, try the `-n` option  to control the interval between each update.

Thus, the following would call tail every 2 seconds

```
$ watch -n 2 tail -n 15 mylogfile.txt
```

while this one polls it every 1 second

```
$ watch -n 1 tail -n 15 mylogfile.txt
```

Answer (score 16):

You could stream the logfile running less and pressing SHIFT + F that will stream the file using less.
`$ less mylogfile.txt`
Then just press SHIFT + F and it will stream. I think it is convenient for monitoring log files that update.

Comment: That's a very nice one!

Comment: Indeed, not what I was looking for but close. You should also be able to use `less +F mylogfile.txt` as the manual says it it is similar in behavior to tail -f. If you, dear comment reader haven't used `less +G mylogfile.txt` yet, then you now know how to immediately jump to the end of a log file. A useful and great time saver on old an poorly maintained systems.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe you find the `-d` param handy.

```
man watch
```

> -d
>                 Highlight the differences between successive updates.  Option will read optional argument that changes highlight to be
>   permanent, allowing to see what has changed at least once since first
>   iteration.

Comment: Good catch too!

Answer (score 0):

In Solaris, AIX or HPUX or UNIX-like (including Linux) you can use scripts to monitoring logs or anything like that:

```
while true; 
    clear; 
    do date; 
    echo ;
    echo "MONITORING LOG IN "/path/to/file.log": "; 
    echo "Obs.: Last 20 lines of a logfile:
    echo ;
    tail -20 /path/to/file.log;
    echo ;
sleep 5; 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I've decided to write myself a bash function that does exactly that. Pasting the script here for those who want it. "`ntail`" preserves the last N lines and has a timeout before updating the screen to minimize flickering effects when stdout updates too often.

You can try it out with the following example command, for which the screen updates should preserve the "date", but render a scrolling effect on the stdout of the for loop:

```bash
date; for i in $(seq 1 2000); do echo $i; sleep 0.03; done | ntail 10
```

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# Display last N lines of input like tail, but cleaning the screen before every update.
# Example: date; for i in $(seq 1 2000); do echo $i; sleep 0.03; done | ntail 10

function ntail {

    # default to 10 lines of tail output
    NUM_LINES=${1:-10}

    # gets the current time in milliseconds
    function mstime() {
        date +%s%3N
    }

    LAST_UPDATE=$(mstime)   # last time the screen was updated
    NEEDS_REFRESH=false     # whether to refresh the screen
    SCREEN_BUFFER_SIZE=0    # number of lines on the screen
    while IFS= read -r NEW_LINE; do

        # concatenate new the new line to the buffer
        TAIL_BUFFER="$TAIL_BUFFER$NEW_LINE"$'\n'

        # if last update is greater than 100ms, refresh screen
        if [ $(($(mstime) - LAST_UPDATE)) -gt 100 ]; then
            NEEDS_REFRESH=true
        fi

        # refresh screen if needed
        if [ "$NEEDS_REFRESH" = true ]; then

            # reduce buffer size to last NUM_LINES lines
            TAIL_BUFFER=$(echo "$TAIL_BUFFER" | tail -n "$NUM_LINES")$'\n'

            # clear the last SCREEN_BUFFER_SIZE lines, preserving the stdout above that
            for _ in $(seq 1 "$SCREEN_BUFFER_SIZE"); do
                printf "\033[1A\033[2K"
            done

            # print the new buffer
            printf "%s" "$TAIL_BUFFER"

            SCREEN_BUFFER_SIZE=$(echo "$TAIL_BUFFER" | wc -l)
            SCREEN_BUFFER_SIZE=$((SCREEN_BUFFER_SIZE - 1))
            LAST_UPDATE=$(mstime)
            NEEDS_REFRESH=false

        fi

    done < /dev/stdin
}

ntail "$@"
```